# How to turn entire JSON response into array of values

Tags: javascript

I've got a jSON response in the following format:

```
var json = [{id: 1, name:'test'}, {id:2, name:'bla'}]
```

What I need is an array like this:

```
[[1,'test'],[2,'bla']]
```

I know that when I do `Object.values(json[0])`, I can get only the values for the first item. But I need the entire array. What is the correct way of doing `Object.values(json)`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` method with `Object.values`.

```js
var json = [{id: 1, name:'test'}, {id:2, name:'bla'}]
var values = json.map(Object.values);
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.prototype.map` and `Object.values` :

```js
var json = [{id: 1, name:'test'}, {id:2, name:'bla'}]
var res = json.map(o => Object.values(o));
console.log(res);
```